# Is there a way to display the directory / folder size?

Tags: javascript, html

So, I've been searching everywhere for what I'm looking for and a few times I thought I struck gold but 99% of the time it wasn't in the correct language.

Does anyone know how I can output the size of my site's directory folder in HTML using JS. I tried using `var x = new Date(document.lastModified);document.write(document.lastModified)` but instead of `document.lastModified` I tried `document.size` but no, that didn't work.

And 50% of what I did manage to find that I thought would work, as well didn't.

Comment: Javascript runs on the client.  How would it interrogate what's on the server?

Comment: The is no API to access that data from the OS. I assume it is considered a security risk of some sort

Comment: I put JS because I slightly know about Javascript, anyway. What I want to try and do is have the size of the folder outputted on my site if that makes sense, so. Say the folder is "3GB", I want it to say that on the page. So, "The size of the site is currently: <directory size>". Hopefully that makes any sense, not the best at wording stuff.

Comment: You use serverside command which will pull the dir size and report it to the frontend. Like PHP, Python, nodejs, Ruby,Java..